# Where is windows backup settings stored in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, scheduled-tasks

I use windows [backup and restore] utility to create a scheduled backup on every Sunday 7PM.

I was wondering that where I can find this setting file? If it is a scheduled task, I should be able to find it in task scheduler....but it is not there. so where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings are found within Windows Backup's utility itself.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-change-automatic-backup-settings#1TC=windows-7

The scheduled task does exist though.  It's under `Scheduled Tasks`, `Task Scheduler Library`, `Microsoft`, `Windows`, `WindowsBackup`.